# SCX 3201g Duplex ( long edge and short edge )

Tags: printing, samsung

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SCX 3201 G Duplex Printing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173752/scx-3201-g-duplex-printing)

I am unable to set it to `Two-sided` (long edge and short edge ) . As soon as i click "apply" or "ok" , it changes back to one sided. My printer support this function under windows.

[image]

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 04e8:3441 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
```