# How do I get duplex printing working on a Samsung SCX 3201 G?

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

I am using this Samsing SCX 3201g. I have installed Samsung Unified Drivers from Samsung's Site.

[image]

It is doesn't have Any Option for Duplex printing. Using same Printer on Windows 7 supports Duplex Printing.

Long Edge 
Short Edge Settings.

How do i configure these to work in Ubuntu 12.10 if my Printer supports it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Samsung SCX 6322 DN Series and this was sorted by installing the driver from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to see a fix for this.  I'm having the exact same problem with my networked Epson Workforce 630 printer.

I've seen people recommend editing the settings via

localhost:631/printers/

in a web browser, but my printer doesn't have the relevant duplex printing options there either.

There's also printer-config-system.  (System Settings -> Printing).

I know it's not my printer that is the problem.  It's an excellent all-in-one printer that works great in Windows7.